# How can I extract these multiple regex groups in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-group

I have string inputs in the following format:

```
my.strings <- c("FACT11", "FACT11:FACT20", "FACT1sometext:FACT20", "FACT1text with spaces:FACT20", "FACT14:FACT20", "FACT1textAnd1312:FACT2etc", "FACT12:FACT22:FACT31")
```

I would like to extract all the "FACT"s and the first number following FACT. So the result from this example would be:

```
c("FACT1", "FACT1 FACT2", "FACT1 FACT2", "FACT1 FACT2", "FACT1 FACT2", "FACT1 FACT2", "FACT1 FACT2 FACT3")
```

Alternatively, the result could be a list, where each element of the list is a vector with 1 up to 3 items.

What I got so far is:

```
gsub("(FACT[1-3]).*?:(FACT[1-3]).*", '\\1 \\2', my.strings)
# [1] "FACT11"       "FACT1 FACT2 " "FACT1 FACT2 " "FACT1 FACT2 " "FACT1 FACT2 " "FACT1 FACT2 "
# [7] "FACT1 FACT2 " "FACT1 FACT2 "
```

It kinda looks good, except for the "FACT11" for the first element instead of "FACT1" (dropping the second "1"), and missing the "FACT3" for the last element of `my.strings`. But adding another group to `gsub` somehow messes the whole thing up.

```
gsub("(FACT[1-3]).*?:(FACT[1-3]).*?:(FACT[1-3]).*?", '\\1 \\2 \\3', my.strings)
# [1] "FACT11"                       "FACT11:FACT20"                "FACT1sometext:FACT20"        
# [4] "FACT1text with spaces:FACT20" "FACT14:FACT20"                "FACT1textAnd1312:FACT2etc"   
# [7] "FACT12:FACT21"                "FACT1 FACT2 FACT31"
```

So how can I properly extract the groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a base R approach, too:

```
> m <- regmatches(my.strings, gregexpr("FACT[1-3]", my.strings))
> sapply(m, paste, collapse=" ")
[1] "FACT1"            
[2] "FACT1 FACT2"      
[3] "FACT1 FACT2"      
[4] "FACT1 FACT2"      
[5] "FACT1 FACT2"      
[6] "FACT1 FACT2"      
[7] "FACT1 FACT2 FACT3"
```

Extract all matches with your `FACT[1-3]` (or `FACT[0-9]`, or `FACT\\d`) pattern, and then "join" them with a space.

Answer (score 4):

An option would be `str_extract_all` from `stringr` to extract all the 'FACT' substring followed by one digit that can be 1 to 3 (`[1-3]`) into a `list` of `vector`s.  Then, `map` through the `list` elements and `paste` the `vector`s to a single strings

```
library(tidyverse)
str_extract_all(my.strings, "FACT[1-3]") %>%
            map_chr(paste, collapse= ' ')
#[1] "FACT1"             "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"      
#[4] "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"      
#[7] "FACT1 FACT2 FACT3"
```

---

Or using `gsub` from `base R`

```
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", trimws(gsub("(FACT[1-3])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.",
                       " ", my.strings, perl = TRUE)))
#[1] "FACT1"             "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"      
#[4] "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"      
#[7] "FACT1 FACT2 FACT3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would you also have a solution in case I don't want to leave base R?

Answer (score 0):

Another base R alternative:

This solution uses the fact the `FACT` end in a one-digit number.

```
my.strings %>%  
  gsub("(\\d)\\d*", "\\1:", ., perl = TRUE) %>% 
  strsplit(":") %>%
  sapply(function(x) paste(x[grepl("FACT", x)], collapse = " "))

[1] "FACT1"             "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"      
[5] "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2"       "FACT1 FACT2 FACT3"
```